# Why does my binary search only work with if statements in this order?

Tags: c, search

I'm wondering why my binary search code doesn't work with this code (it returns everything as found):

```
int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = len-1;
    int mid = (first+last)/2;
    while (first <= last) {
        mid = floor((first+last)/2);            
        if (target = arr[mid]) {
            return 1;
        } else if (target < arr[mid]) {
            last = mid-1;
        } else {
            first = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But the following works. The only difference is the order of if statements in the while loop.

```
int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = len-1;
    int mid = (first+last)/2;
    while (first <= last) {
        mid = floor((first+last)/2);            
        if (arr[mid] < target) {
            first = mid+1;
        } else if (target = arr[mid]) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else { //arr[mid] < target
            last = mid-1;
        }           
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: if (target **==** arr[mid])

Comment: does the second code really works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (target = arr[mid])
```

This is an *assignment*, not just a comparison. It will make `target` be equal to `arr[mid]` (and then enter the block, unless the value is `0`).

Comment: D'oh... missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`if (target = arr[mid]) {` really? Do you mean `==`?

Just in addition to the answers mentioned, the `=` operator assigns and then returns the value assigned if the assignment was successful. For eg. if you do `printf("%d", (a = 10));` you will see `10` printed. So, when you use the assignment operator in a `if` statement, it boils down to something like `if (10)` (or some other number) and thus your `if` block gets executed. I hope it is obvious why `if (a = 0)` wont get you to execute the `if` block. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (target = arr[mid])
```

this is wrong as it assigns a value to target
and apparently you want to compare, so do this

```
if (target == arr[mid])
```

use the double `==`